# Does this tattoo mean honesty?

Tags: translation, meaning

[image]I was told this meant truth and honesty when I got it. Is that the true meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Your tattoo read "実"/ざ‐ね/

It is the Japanese shinjitai of 實.
The simplified Chinese character of 實 is 实

诚实 means 'honest'

实 by itself can mean:

1. "solid" as in 結实
2. "actual/true" as in "实在/真实"
3. "fruit" as in "果实"

实 doesn't specifically mean honesty in Chinese, maybe you should ask what "実" usually mean in Japanese Language SE

Answer (score 0):

The best choices for honesty in Chinese are:

诚

诚实

正直

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

> I was told this meant truth and honesty when I got it. Is that the
> true meaning?

Your tattoo is a character used for historical reasons to write words with similar meanings in both Japanese and Chinese; however, your tattoo is written in a revised form generally used only in modern Japanese and would therefore be presumed to write a Japanese word with Japanese pronunciation.  You should therefore ask your question on the Japanese stack exchange, which is a sister site to this one, rather than on this site that is focused specifically on Chinese.

Just to anticipate what you would most likely hear, I can say that this character can be used to write words that include the meanings "[truth](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AE%9F#Etymology_2)" and "[fidelity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AE%9F#Etymology_4)" (the two pronunciations actually have similar ranges of meanings); however, this character can also be used to write words with other meanings.  I don't think the character can mean honesty by itself, since in that context, it has more the connotation of being faithful or true to your word, rather than meaning "not to tell lies."